# Get height of variable children in a functional component in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-animated

I am trying to get the height of children in my component in order to implement an animation.

This is the card component
[image: Not expanded card component]

Expanded with children
[image]

I'd like to get the height of the children components so I can animate a height value in order to achieve an animated expansion.

```
{expanded ? (
        <>
          <Animated.View style={{height: someAnimatedHeight}}>
            <View onLayout={handleLayout}>
              {children}
            </View>
          </Animated.View>
          <PromoCodeArea />
        </>
      ) : (
        <PromoCodeArea />
      )}
```

handleLayout

```
const handleLayout = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    setContainerHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height);
  };
```

However, `handleLayout` doesn't provide the height until the card is expanded. I can get the animation to work with a hardcoded size.

I'd like the animation to be flexible and expand to the height of the children.

When not expanded `handleLayout` returns a value of 0, therefore I can't set the `toValue`:

```
const startAnimation = () => {
    Animated.spring(heightAnimation, {
      toValue: 125, <-- like this to be based on the height of children
    }).start();
  };
```

I haven't been able to find examples of this being achieved using functional components and hooks.

Answer (score 0):

One strategy (which isn't pretty but works for me) is to initially set the children style to opacity 0 (so no-one sees it) and position 'absolute' so it doesn't interfere with your visible layout and don't set the height to 0 so it renders at the required size. Once it's been rendered (consider using useLayoutEffect) get the height from onLayout and save it - then set the style back to how you have it at the moment before anyone gets the chance to interact with it.